# In Playwright wait for data rows to be loaded on page

Tags: javascript, css, user-interface, playwright, playwright-java

I open page and waiting until data is loaded to displayed rows.
In selenium it works like this:

```
private final String dataRowXpath = "*//div[@ref='eCenterContainer']//div[@role='row']";
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, ofMinutes(1L));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.numberOfElementsToBeMoreThan(By.xpath(dataRowXpath), 0));
```

I need to do it using Playwright. I written below code:

```
String dataRowCSSSelector = div[ref='eCenterContainer'] > div[role='row']
String function = String.format("() => document.querySelectorAll(\"%s\").length > 0", dataRowCSSSelector);
page.waitForFunction(function);
```

But unfortunately it throws timeout exception although I see that data rows are loaded:

```
com.microsoft.playwright.TimeoutError: Error {
  message='Timeout 30000ms exceeded.
  name='TimeoutError
  stack='TimeoutError: Timeout 30000ms exceeded.
```

Comment: Please share a syntactically correct, runnable [mcve] with a target site you're automating. Thanks.

Comment: As above you need to share either the site or the html snippet. We cannot give an answer to a problem that has missing detail

Answer (score 0):

Why are you not using Playwright locators?

https://playwright.dev/java/docs/locators#strictness

Try with this:

```
assertThat(page.locator("*//div[@ref='eCenterContainer']//div[@role='row']").first()).isVisible();
```

Comment: One note to your response is that when you use xpath as locator() argument is should be prefixed by xpath=

Comment: Anyway is doesn't work. I see in debugger that : first().isVisible() return false as well as count() returns 0. It's strange because on previous page such code works. The only difference is that previous page is not updated after displayed and this page is  constantly being updated.  Could this be the reason ?

Comment: xpath should be detected by Playwright.
In general, Playwright should use retry-ability for this assertion. Maybe try to use ""*//div[@ref='eCenterContainer']//div[@role='row'][0]" as xpath and remove .first()